# Installed Application Fails To Load MySQL.Data.DLL?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, installation, mysql.data

I have an application that runs perfectly on my system (both in the IDE, and installed), but fails completely when installed on any other system.

I moved an abridged version of the source code over to see if I could figure out what the issue was, and much to my boundless fury, I discovered the error occurred when the program attempted to reference a class contained in another library which made use of the MySQL.Data.DLL file...

[Insert endless string of curses, swears, and otherwise R-rated language here].

Why? WHY? *WHY?!* ***WHY?!?!*** ***SERIOUSY - WHAT THE HELL?!***

Comment: possible reason could be the mysql version mismatch. on your client machine.
have you compared it with your mysql version?

Comment: Okay so... if the MySQL connector is installed on the client system it can screw this up?

Comment: it should be install over there.. and the version must be same as your application's MySql connector, otherwise how can it would find out the MySql.Data.dll??? it would surely screq this up

Comment: Okay. I'm looking at the install directory. It's there. I see it. Unless I'm suffering from some catastrophic rage-induced hallucination, I am seeing the file there.

Comment: Your machine's MySql connector version and client's machine versions are same???

Comment: They are now and I am testing this with the client system having the MySQL Connector installed on it but that's not the problem. The average layman user won't have the MySQL connector installed. What am I supposed to do when this program is released for general circulation and John Q. User can't run it because they don't have this obscure... thing installed?

Comment: well its another issue, your application must install all of its per-requisits. Now just tell me that matching versions solved your problem??? or should I give you another hints or options to solve that specific problem?

Comment: I am going to guess that it worked and that there is another issue (Running the source that issue has vanished and there is now something else so it's like a cancer patient coming in with Pneumonia -.-; shoot me now).

Comment: well see my answer, if you are getting other issues too, then you have to tell us for help you, if i could help you then you can mark my answer.

Comment: It's alright I was able to resolve the other thing since I was familiar with it. This was infuriating though - thanks for your help.

Comment: you are most welcome, i can help you though if u tell me that what kinda error you are getting.
btw it is hard to understand you english :P im not good in it :)

Comment: Not getting anymore errors (Thanks for the help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use MySql in your applications and install on client machines, it will search `MySql.Data.dll` in client machine and goes to the path

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net X.X.X\Assemblies\` (assuming you have installed MySql connector in C drive)

Exploring `Assemblies` folder you would see this `MySql.Data.dll` check this file's version and similarly check your's `MySql.Data.dll` they must be same.

> *The average layman user won't have the MySQL connector installed. What am I supposed to do when this program is released for general circulation and John Q. User can't run it because they don't have this obscure... thing installed?*

Your application must **Package** all of its per-requisites with it, so when client install it, per-requisites should also install with your software.
Lets suppose I developed an application with `MySql connector 6.9.6.0`.

DO the following things

1. Package MySql Connector with your software build
2. specify `MySql Connector` version in App.Config file.

   ```
    <system.data>
       <DbProviderFactories>
           <clear/>
           <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
           <add name="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data,Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
       </DbProviderFactories>
   </system.data>
   ```

Now client machine will specifically search for the mentioned version in `app.config`.

By the way these two points are optional, 
if you don't do these then you have to take care of each and everything, as your are doing now.